# problem with driver when upgrade to jessie

Tags: driver, raspbian-jessie

I upgrade my Raspbian from Wheezy to Jessie. now when I want use Gstreamer, I face the following error:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
```

I think it somehow related to hardware accelerated video decoding. but I don't know what to do.
can anyone help me please?